# use 7 zip to delete parenthesis

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I'm trying to build a loop here to delete files that have trailing () after the file name. Not sure how to accomplish this in a batch file. I only want to keep the original file.

now I can remove files with words but this is where I'm stuck.

```
      for /r  %dir1% %%a in ( *.zip) do  7z d %%a *(1)* -r
```

[testfiles with ()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SyOR.png)

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Could you please clean up your code example.  I am pretty sure you are not using nested `FOR /R` command to try to accomplish this task.

Comment: I would think this is all you need: `for /r "%dir1%" %%a in (*.zip) do 7z d "%%a" "*(*)*"`

Comment: @Squashman I am using a nested loop. the main loop is for a folder directory with zip files and another loop is for the files in the zip folder. I have several file names I need to loop through.  However that *(*)* might not work because sometimes I do have extra () in the file name I'm really trying to exclude duplicated copies of the file so really it has to be specific to (1) value.

Comment: I would advise that you take the [tour]. Read [ask] a good question and in the future provide a [mcve] of the code you are using.  Your code is not a verifiable example as your usage of the nested `FOR` commands are not being utilized.

Comment: good note I will take that under consideration going forward. Also, I updated my code example. 
thanks